# How to make '?' non gready

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I have a CLASSPATH value `C:\Windows\abc;C:\Windows\def;C:\Windows\ghi` and need to get `C:\Windows\def`. Value of CLASSPATH can vary except `def` of middle path (or only one path `\..\..\parent\def` be present in CLASSPATH).

Regex is `;?(.*def)` but it is matching `C:\Windows\abc;C:\Windows\def`

I want only `C:\Windows\def` regardless of presence of `;` just before `C:\Windows\def`

What is the proper way to achieve it ?

Comment: `??` is a non-greedy `?` in many engines, but it seems what you want is actually `([^;]*def)`.

Comment: You may try [`[^;]+\\def(?=;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/OERsBx/3).

Comment: Is it used in JavaScript?

Comment: It is used in PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greediness isn’t the issue here; rather, you need to exclude semicolons.

Match a sequence of characters not containing `;` but ending in `def`:

```
[^;]*def
```

and make sure it’s followed by the end of the string or a `;`:

```
[^;]*def(?=;|$)
```

Comment: Now, the `[^;]*def(?=;|$)` regex will match `C:\Windows\abcdef` in  `C:\Windows\abcdef;C:\Windows\def;C:\Windows\ghi`. I think OP needs to only match the value with ``\def`` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OP never said that wasn’t intended, but it’s not hard to add a ``\\`` before the `def`.

Comment: Yeah, they are usually not that talkative when asked for requirements :(